# Single operation with multiple callbacks in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

How a single operation with multiple callbacks (e.g. START with some params, PROGRESS called multiple times with other params and END with other params) should be exposed in RxJava?

I'm thinking to use a wrapper object that contains an observable for each kind of callback and that a subscription on any of those observable triggers the start of the operation with the other binded on the same underlying operation

**EDIT:** An example callback interface for a download operation

```
interface Callback {
    void onDownloadStarted(long contentLength, String mimeType, String nameHint);
    void onDownloadProgress(long downloadedBytes);
    void onDownloadCompleted(File file);
}
```

Comment: What operation do you want to perform?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos added an example callback interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of your operation as an `Observable<Status>` where

```
public static class Info {
    public final long contentLength;
    public final String mimeType;
    public final String nameHint;
    public Info(long contentLength, String mimeType, String nameHint) {
        this.contentLength = contentLength;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
        this.nameHint = nameHint;
    }
}
public static class Status {
    public final Info info;
    public final long downloadProgress; //in bytes
    public final Optional<File> file;
    public Status(Info info, long downloadProgress, Optional<File> file) {
        this.info = info;
        this.downloadProgress = downloadProgress;
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Then you could model your download operation as:

`Observable<Status> download();`

You get no emissions till the download has started and the final emission has the `File` result.

You could use it like this:

```
download()
   .doOnNext(status -> System.out.println(
        "downloaded " 
        + status.downloadProgress 
        + " bytes of " + status.contentLength))
   .last()
   .doOnNext(status -> System.out.println(
        "downloaded " + status.file.get())
   .doOnError(e -> logError(e))
   .subscribe();
```

Comment: Something that scares me is the object allocation / gc pauses (i'm on android) for events like  a progress based on bytes that will be generated a lot. In this case on every buffer read/write (eg. 8K) it will allocate a new Status object?

Comment: Yes that's right, but you don't have to emit every 8K. You have all the count information you need to ensure that you only emit every say 1% or 5% and that's a trivial amount of gc.